# Get All Strings between tags and echo them?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get content between two strings PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445506/get-content-between-two-strings-php)

Ok, here is my delima:

here is an example of my $content :

```
<!--nextpage-->First Title Here<!--nexttitle-->

some more text here

and here and here and here

a little more here!

<!--nextpage-->Second Title Here<!--nexttitle-->

some more text here

and here and here and here

a little more here!

<!--nextpage-->Third Title Here<!--nexttitle-->

some more text here

and here and here and here

a little more here!
```

How could I run a function that finds all "get_all_strings_between()" and echo them at the top of the $content:

```
**First Title Here** / **Second Title Here** / **Third Title Here**

and then my content HERE!
```

THanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly this regexp will do it:

```
function get_all_strings_between($content) {
    preg_match_all('/<!--nextpage-->([^<]*)<!--nexttitle-->/', $content, $m);

    return implode(' / ', $m[1]);
}

// then you echo get_all_strings_between($content) where you need it
```

If I'm incorrect, please provide more info what are these `nextpage` and `nexttitle` tags? Are they appear like this literally?

Comment: They were part of a CMS.. just strings in a database. Thanks for your comment. I will try it out!!

Comment: You Got IT!! Wow, I researched the heck out of this and yours was the only once that worked for me!! Maybe because I am such a noob, but thanks so much. Is the speed for this function fast ?? Or is there a Faster way, some of the $content strings I have are pretty large....??

Comment: Regexps are not the fastest tool, but don't think about performance until you actually have a problem with it. Try running it for large strings, see what happens.