# is there a PHP function to find a middle string?

Tags: php, string, strstr

Ok to be clear ill give an example

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$domain = strstr($email, '@');
echo $domain; // prints @example.com

$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
echo $user; // prints name
```

as it says, it prints what before '@' using true, and blank to print what follows @

im looking for a function to print  @ itself by giving it 2 strings and grab what between them

like this

```
  $string= 'someXthing';
  $tograb = phpfunction("some","thing");
  echo $tograb; // should be printing X
```

^ this doesnt work, im just writing it to explain

Comment: i would really like to see a case where you can use this. also, just use regex for that

Comment: what you need is a regex

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445506/get-content-between-two-strings-php

Comment: [Documentation is your friend](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know of a native function that does that but you can use regular expression

```
$string= 'someXthing';
preg_match("/some(.*)thing/",$string,$matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Read More about [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: that kinda worked but how to make it to only print X without some thing

Comment: @LiliAbedinpour the variable $matches is an array, so you can `echo $matches[1]` to see the matched string.

Comment: ohhh sorry yes got it now, thanks im fine with this but i think there should be a function for that, i guess it will mostly be needed in future ! thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

From internet

```
function GetBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}
```

[Original code](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/get-between.htm)

Answer (score 0):

For the example you said, you can use strpos to print X like this:

```
$string = 'someXthing';

$start = strpos($string, "some") + strlen("some");
$end = strpos($string, "thing", $start);
$tograb = substr($string, $start, $end - $start);

echo $tograb;
```

and X will be printed.