# How to extract text between 2 tags in php

Tags: php

I need to locate 2 tags in a lump of text and keep whatever text is between them.

For example if the "Begin" tag was `-----start-----` and the "End" tag was `-----end-----`

Given this text:

```
rtyfbytgyuibg-----start-----isnv4b987b6vdc5y6ughnjmn9b8v76ctyubinn98b76r
-----end-----gcgkhjkn
```

I need keep just the text between the 2 tags: `isnv4b987b6vdc5y6ughnjmn9b8v76ctyubinn98b76r`

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Yan.. i had not tried anything as i was not sure what php function could do it.. but im now using preg_match

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways:

```
$lump = 'rtyfbytgyuibg-----start-----isnv4b987b6vdc5y6ughnjmn9b8v76ctyubinn98b76r-----end-----gcgkhjkn';
$start_tag = '-----start-----';
$end_tag = '-----end-----';

// method 1
if (preg_match('/'.preg_quote($start_tag).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($end_tag).'/s', $lump, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}

// method 2 (faster)
$startpos = strpos($lump, $start_tag) + strlen($start_tag);
if ($startpos !== false) {
    $endpos = strpos($lump, $end_tag, $startpos);
    if ($endpos !== false) {
        echo substr($lump, $startpos, $endpos - $startpos);
    }
}

// method 3 (if you need to find multiple occurrences)
if (preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote($start_tag).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($end_tag).'/s', $lump, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: Hiya Mark, thanks for these 3 im using function getTextBetweenTags($string)
{
$pattern = "/-----BEGIN PKCS7-----(.*?)-----END PKCS7-----/";
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
return $matches[1];
}

$txt = getTextBetweenTags($mytext);

Comment: Please see my correction to method #2 to check whether the end tag was found.

Comment: @john, I recommend that you use the if() statement as I did; otherwise you'll get errors if there is no match.

Comment: `preg_quote()` does not have a default value for the delimiter character.  You have to explicitly nominate the slash character.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$start = '-----start-----';
$end   = '-----end-----';
$string = 'rtyfbytgyuibg-----start-----isnv4b987b6vdc5y6ughnjmn9b8v76ctyubinn98b76r-----end-----gcgkhjkn';
$output = strstr( substr( $string, strpos( $string, $start) + strlen( $start)), $end, true);
echo $output;
```

This [will print](http://viper-7.com/2a7y2L):

```
isnv4b987b6vdc5y6ughnjmn9b8v76ctyubinn98b76r
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to compensate with `strlen($start)` instead of `+1` in the 2nd parameter of the `substr`?

Comment: The params for substr() are $string, $start, $length

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys - Just tested it and it should work now

Comment: I was going to suggest storing the start pos `strpos( $string, $start) + strlen( $start))` in another var and obtaining the length by `strpos($end)` minus the start pos, but your `strstr` is much nicer. +1

Answer (score -1):

Here are some solutions using functions:
[Get content between two strings PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445506/get-content-between-two-strings-php)

You can use Regex. Here is an example:

```php
<?php
$haystack = 'rtyfbytgyuibg-----start-----isnv4b987b6vdc5y6ughnjmn9b8v76ctyubinn98b76r
-----end-----gcgkhjknrtyfbytgyuibg-----start-----y6ughnjmn9b8v76ctyubinn98b76r
-----end-----gcgkhjkn';

$start = '-----start-----';
$end = '-----end-----';
$pattern = '/'.$start.'(.+)\s*'.$end.'/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $haystack, $needles);

//If you have Multiples matches
foreach($needles[1] as $needle) {
  echo $needle;
}

//If you want single
echo $needles[1][0]; //isnv4b987b6vdc5y6ughnjmn9b8v76ctyubinn98b76r
```

Comment: So you copy-pasted the whole other answer just to make a note about one line of code? Why not suggest an edit?

Comment: Who do you think you are fooling? Your 4th technique was already posted by [nickb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277635/2943403).  You could have left comments to use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` if necessary, BUT the asked question does not benefit from `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.  `preg_quote()` does not include slash as the default delimiter. `preg_match_all()` doesn't make sense if you aren't going loop through the results.  This answer adds nothing beneficial to this page -- it only gives flawed, redundant, and useless advice for the asked question.

Comment: @mickmackusa I posted a different solution using regex

Comment: The accepted answer already demonstrates proper regex escaping of the start and end strings as well as an adequate implementation of a multi-line-safe capture group.  This answer still does not add any valuable insights.  If you believe that this page is a duplicate, then flag this page as a duplicate instead of answering it.  If I wasn't on strike, I would hammer this page closed with your linked page.