# PHP function getAllBetweenStr using regular expression

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get content between two strings PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445506/get-content-between-two-strings-php)

I am trying to create a php function that will return an array of all occurrences of text between two substrings. I am useless at regular expression and would find this very handy, I'm sure there is already a very nice one out there but I can't find it.

```
    function getAllBetweenStr($input, $start, $end)
    {
         //DO STUFF

         //RETURN ARRAY
    }


$inputStr ="<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc' class='currentLink' hreflang='en'>abc1/a>
<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc/b1'  hreflang='en'>abc2</a>
<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc/b2'  hreflang='en'>abc3</a>
<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc/b3'  hreflang='en'>abc4</a>";


$linkStr = array();
$linkStr = getAllBetweenStr($inputStr, "http://formaco4/en/'", "'  hreflang")
```

The return array would be like this
Array([0] => "abc/b1", [1] => "abc/b2", ... , [n] => "gingers/rule")

I have this function already if it helps:

```
    function getBetweenStr($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);    
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);
    }
```

Comment: and this is actually what preg_match / preg_match_all (in your case) is made for ...

Comment: you define $linkstr as a array. Then you define $linkstr as a string (returning the substr) when you want to have it as an array you have to define it as $link[].

Comment: *(related)* [How to parse and proccess HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this will work - It uses `preg_match_all` to capture anything between the two `$start` and `$end` strings.

```
function getBetweenStr($string, $start, $end)
{
    preg_match_all( '/' . preg_quote( $start, '/') . '(.*?)' . preg_quote( $end, '/') . '/', $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine doesn't use the preg_match function. Hopefully you will find this useful

Try this, I've also provided a better function for you (:
:

```
function stribet($inputstr, $delimiterLeft, $delimiterRight) {
    $posLeft = stripos($inputstr, $delimiterLeft) + strlen($delimiterLeft);
    $posRight = stripos($inputstr, $delimiterRight, $posLeft);
    return substr($inputstr, $posLeft, $posRight - $posLeft);
}

$links = array("<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc' class='currentLink' hreflang='en'>abc1/a>", "<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc/b1'  hreflang='en'>abc2</a>");

foreach ($links as $linkstr){
$linkstr = stribet($linkstr, "http://formaco4/en/'", "'  hreflang='");
//echo $linkstr;
$data[] = $linkstr;
}

print_r($data);
```

if you would just like to stick to normal string function, try exploding `<a`
then use the foreach loop to get your data.

Something like

```
$inputStr ="<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc' class='currentLink' hreflang='en'>abc1/a>
<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc/b1'  hreflang='en'>abc2</a>
<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc/b2'  hreflang='en'>abc3</a>
<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc/b3'  hreflang='en'>abc4</a>";
$inputArray = explode ("<a", $inputStr);
  foreach ($inputArray as $linkstr){
    $linkstr = stribet($linkstr, "http://formaco4/en/'", "'  hreflang='");
    //echo $linkstr;
    $data[] = $linkstr;
    }

    print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really worth learning regular expressions.  They're very powerful and useful:

```
preg_match_all('|'.preg_quote($start).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($end).'|', $input, $linkStr);
```

In your example this would build a regular expression of:

```
|http:\/\/formaco4\/en\/\(.*?)  hreflang|
```

The parens () tell it to capture that part of the string.  The ".*?" within the parens instruct it to catch all characters up to what follows.

Comment: Need to escape `$start` and `$end`, otherwise they can break the regex.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that after I submitted. I was adding it as you typed your comment :)

Comment: Using `|` as delimiter is quite irregular, especially since it's also used for alternation :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (untested):

```
function find_occurencies($start, $search, $end)
{
    $start = stripslashes($start);
    $end = stripslashes($end);
    $search = stripslashes($search);

    $pattern = '%'. $start . '([\s\w]+)?' . $end . '%';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $search, $matches);

    // Print the matches (should)
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Need to escape `$start` and `$end`, otherwise they can break the regex.

Comment: well, yes ... I was still updating ;)

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0

Comment: It is nearly there but some of the characters in the input strings break the regex

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function getAllBetweenStr($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $array_to_return = array();
        for($i=0; $i<count(explode($start,$string))-1; $i++) {
        $str_0 = explode($start,$string);
        $str_1 = explode($end, $str_0[1]);
        $array_to_return[$i] = $str_1[0];
        }
        return $array_to_return;
    }

$inputStr ="<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc' class='currentLink' hreflang='en'>abc1</a>
<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc/b1'  hreflang='en'>abc2</a>
<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc/b2'  hreflang='en'>abc3</a>
<a href='http://formaco4/en/abc/b3'  hreflang='en'>abc4</a>";
$linkStr = getAllBetweenStr($inputStr, "hreflang='en'>", "</a>");
print_r ($linkStr);
?>
```