# Sorting urls based on some value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, amazon-s3

I have array of urls stored. Every url has some format. I need to sort the urls array.
Like

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos/1358086239.jpg?response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI2U3TRTNGXNCQHYQ&Expires=1359636889&Signature=l9GnekYT0wK9AznkPWWjBuCRgBY%3D
https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos/1358066630.jpg?response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI2U3TRTNGXNCQHYQ&Expires=1359636889&Signature=l9GnekYT0wK9AznkPWWjBuCRgBY%3D
```

These urls are reutned by amazon S3 PHP SDK [get_object_url](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/get_object_url) method.

I have 1000 of these urls but i want to sort these urls based on `1358086239.jpg` value this value is everytime an integer value and i want to sort urls in Asc order based on this value.

How can i sort these urls array. i tried using php builtin function [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) But it did not helped.

Comment: Strip the leading URL (always same?) then sort on the resulting value.

Comment: Hint: the answer to Jan Hancic's (pardon, but I don't have the accents on my keyboard =) comment is *not*: how do I do that? The proper answer is: I tried this, it failed in this way, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If everything before the `[0-9]+.jpg` is always the same, you would expect to be able to sort on the whole thing and get the right result . Why does that not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (fixed):

```
$urls = array(
'https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos/1358086239.jpg?response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI2U3TRTNGXNCQHYQ&Expires=1359636889&Signature=l9GnekYT0wK9AznkPWWjBuCRgBY%3D',
'https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos/1358066630.jpg?response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI2U3TRTNGXNCQHYQ&Expires=1359636889&Signature=l9GnekYT0wK9AznkPWWjBuCRgBY%3D',
);


$list = array();
foreach ($urls as $v) {
   $tmp = explode('https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos/', $v);
   $tmp = explode('.jpg?response-content', $tmp[1]);

   $list[$tmp[0]] = $v;
} 

ksort($list);

var_dump($list);
```

Comment: I tried this, but when i print_r($list); it shows nothing.

Comment: fixed. I first did it out of memory :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, something like this...

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
  $aKey = substr($a, 33, 10);
  $bKey = substr($b, 33, 10);
  return $aKey < $bKey;
}
//$array is sorted now
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to loop through the URLs and assign each one of them into the array, where key would be your number in a file name. Then simply sort it by keys and... you're done!

What you need is:

- [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)
- [a way of getting values between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445506/get-content-between-two-strings-php) - where first string is "<kbd>https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos/</kbd>" and second is "<kbd>.jpg?</kbd>"

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/photos\/\([0-9]+.jpg\)/\1/' | sort` would give the file names in order. A `grep -f` with that as first input and URLs as second would produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$url_array  = array('https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos/1358086239.jpg?response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI2U3TRTNGXNCQHYQ&Expires=1359636889&Signature=l9GnekYT0wK9AznkPWWjBuCRgBY%3D', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos/1358066630.jpg?response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI2U3TRTNGXNCQHYQ&Expires=1359636889&Signature=l9GnekYT0wK9AznkPWWjBuCRgBY%3D');
$res_aray = array();
foreach($url_array as $val){
   preg_match('/photos\/(?P<numb>\d+)\.jpg/', $val, $matches);   
   $res_aray[$matches['numb']] = $val;
}
ksort($res_aray);
print_r($res_aray);

?>
```