# PHP get value between script tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

how to get value between the script tag using php scrapping.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');

//$homepage
<script type="application/ld+json">
  //FETCH ME
/script>
```

Comment: This seems very similar to what you're needing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445506/get-content-between-two-strings-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like the answer you need here, [Get content between two strings PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445506/get-content-between-two-strings-php)

The second answer seems easiest:

```
$out = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
$start = "<script ...>"; // replace ... with exact other text you are maching
$end = "</script>";
$startsAt = strpos($out, $start) + strlen($start);
$endsAt = strpos($out, $end, $startsAt);
$result = substr($out, $startsAt, $endsAt - $startsAt);
```

with `$result` being the as it says result of the content between `$start` and `$end`

For multiple instances, just delete the first occurance from `$out` and repeat:

```
$out = str_replace($start.$result.$end,"",$out);
```

The first occurance is removed, so you can retreive the second occurance. But sure, there may be a more simpler way to get all occurances, not just this.

```
$startsAt = strpos($out, $start) + strlen($start);
$endsAt = strpos($out, $end, $startsAt);
$result = substr($out, $startsAt, $endsAt - $startsAt);
```

Comment: what if there are multiple instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [domDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the  html page.

For example,

```
$response = file_get_contents($targetpath);
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
@$dom->loadHTML($response);
$description = $dom->getElementById('domid');
$description_text = $description->childNodes->item(1)->childNodes->item(3)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: need to get the value between this <script type="application/ld+json"> </script>