# How to get substring between text when the text repeats and includes a new line?

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

I need to extract the second URL from this string:

```
$string = '<td class="table_td">   submitted by   <a href="https://www.example.com/account/user" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> account </a> <br>
 <a href="https://www.URL-I-NEED.com/BKHHZu_A4lu" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">[site]</a>   <a href="https://www.example.com/settings/user/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">[settings]</a></td>';
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445528), and tried these settings:

```
$startTag = ' <a href="';
$endTag = '" target';
```

But it returned the first URL and not the one I need since those tags also appear before the substring I need.

I tried adding the `<br>` before the newline to `$startTag`, but it returned no string.

Basically, I need `$startTag` needs to be `{newline} <a href="`, but I can't figure out how to include that newline.

Or maybe I'm thinking about this wrongly, and there is a simpler way to do this by simply extracting all the URL's from that string, and then simply selecting the 2nd one.

Either way, how can I extract the 2nd URL in the string above?

Comment: Avoid regex for HTML parsing. Use `DOM` parser.

Comment: The newline character in regex is `\n`.

Comment: @anubhava Is there any reasoning for this? I'd love to read about it :)

Comment: [Read this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @anubhava  Thanks, and how would I solve this with the `DOM` parser you are suggesting?

Comment: The second url is always in group 1 - https://regex101.com/r/upLwVm/1 `(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)[\S\s]+?((?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DOM` parser](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) as this code:

```
$string = '<td class="table_td">   submitted by
<a href="https://www.example.com/account/user" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> account </a> <br>
<a href="https://www.URL-I-NEED.com/BKHHZu_A4lu" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">[site]</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com/settings/user/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">[settings]</a>
</td>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($string); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// query all <a...> elements
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//a");

// get 2nd element from the list
$node = $nodelist->item(1);

// extract href attribute
$link = $node->getAttribute('href');

echo $link . "\n";
//=> https://www.URL-I-NEED.com/BKHHZu_A4lu
```

[Code Demo](https://eval.in/835915)

Comment: You can also use `DOMXPath::evaluate` to get the string you want: `$link = $xpath->evaluate("string(//td/a[2]/@href)");`