# Replacing two points and all in between with PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, user-input

I am handling user input. The user is expected to input text in the format of:

#html

***html code goes here***

##html

How can I find every instance of #html and ##html and replace those "tags" and the content in between with a variable I have already defined? I tried str_ireplace() with substr() but that did not work.

Comment: So you want to replace the tags(#html and ##html) then,next replace the whole code between the two with data from a variable (like it doesn't matter what is between the two)?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I what to do.

Comment: Combine str_replace( to replace the tags) with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445506/get-content-between-two-strings-php

Comment: Working perfectly! Thanks!